# Drawing legend with white background in pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqtgraph

I am trying to draw a legend in pyqtgraph using the following code:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

pen_blue = pg.mkPen(cosmetic=True, width=2, color=color_blue)
style = pg.PlotDataItem(pen=pen_blue)
self.legend = self.plotitem.addLegend()
self.legend.setPen("k")
self.legend.setBrush(1.0)
self.legend.addItem(style, " Designed filter")
```

However, when drawing, the grid lines are drawn above the legend brush:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g40XQ.png)

Any ideas on how to solve this?